# Installing Homebrew from process running as root

Tags: macos, unix, process, permissions, homebrew

I have a process running in a client's mac as root able to run commands in it. I need to have that process install Homebrew in the machine and subsequently install other packages using the brew command.

The problem I am having is that brew does not allow me to install it and seems that I cannot use the brew command using root.

I would appreciate any help with this.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Install the stuff using Homebrew in some account *other* than root, and then put the path created by homebrew into root's PATH.